# Never ending for within for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, reactjs

I’m trying to convert text to binary but when my loop runs, it never ends. I cannot figure out why that is so.

Is there a better way to do this?

```
handleBinaryChange: function(e){
    var friendsCopy = this.state.friendsArray;
    for (var i = 0; i < friendsCopy.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < friendsCopy[i].friendsName.length; j++) {   
          console.log(friendsCopy[i].friendsName += friendsCopy[i].friendsName[j].charCodeAt(0).toString(2) + " ");
        }//End of 'j' for
      }//End of 'i' for

      this.setState({
          friendsArray: friendsCopy //make friendsCopy contain the new value for friendsName
      });
    }
}
```

Comment: you are increasing the friendsName in your console.log statement, no?

Comment: Also, it's not a copy of friendsArray, it's another reference to the original array.

Comment: is that not adding the new value to the previous one?

Answer (score 1):

By using `+=` in `friendsCopy[i].friendsName +=` you are modifying `friendsCopy[i].friendsName`. On each iteration it gets longer, so it never stops.

If you only want to output it to the console change it to

```
friendsCopy[i].friendsName + friendsCopy[i].friendsName[j].charCodeAt(0).toString(2) + " ");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are increasing friendsName value with `+=`
in each loop iteration

**simple solution:** use an auxiliary test parameter that stores the starting value:
*this way, test value is fixed throughout the entire loop*
e.g.:

```js
for(var i=0; i<friendsCopy.length; i++){

  var test = friendsCopy[i].friendsName.length; // added this param
  for(var j=0; j<test; j++){   // used it here

    console.log(friendsCopy[i].friendsName += friendsCopy[i].friendsName[j].charCodeAt(0).toString(2) + " ");

  }//End of 'j' for

}//End of 'i' for
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the length of `friendsName` in your break condition, but you keep increasing the length of the string inside the loop:

```
for(var j=0; j<friendsCopy[i].friendsName.length; j++){   
    console.log(friendsCopy[i].friendsName += friendsCopy[i].friendsName[j].charCodeAt(0).toString(2) + " ");
}
```

Note that `friendsCopy[i].friendsName.length` will be executed for each iteration of the loop, not only once at the beginning.

Comment: How am I just repeating his code? I'm pointing out where his mistake is and what he is doing incorrectly. I firmly believe that he will be able to fix this himself, since that should be part of the learning process.

Comment: @Icepickle is there a rule against this approach? please point out.

Comment: @Icepickle got it.

Comment: @warkentien2 not so much a rule, but its definately [not prefered](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303446/is-it-bad-practice-to-post-a-short-answer-first-and-then-add-details-afterwards/303630#303630)

Comment: All, thanks for pointing that out. That was also in no way intentional, I really don't care about being the first one to answer. I just added a bit of information later that I initially didn't think necessary but that seemed helpful. I'll try to avoid this kind of edit in the future! :-)